# Superfish Dropdown menu broken after WP 4.9.5 upgrade

Tags: navigation

I recently installed an SSL certificate and upgraded the site to WordPress 4.9.5

Since then, our superfish drop down nav bar has stopped working. Mixed content is definitely one of the issues but there's also this error and I cant work out how to fix:

```
(index):371 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):371)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):371
i @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
fireWith @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
ready @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
K @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
```

Can someone give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong place as this is not a wordpress-related question (well, or the answer isn't wordpress related), but here is what you do: Get all your files through HTTPS (especially extern files) or just download the extern files and host them on your webspace/server/cloudd. This isn't only more efficient and resistant to unexpected downtimes, but also a big win in data privacy for your users.

It should also fix your "bug", as it seems your superfish is not loading or can not be refered to.